# Android Header Title set Center Position

Tags: java, android, android-actionbar

I work with android (4.0 or higher). I want to use action bar and title of action bar is near with icon . I want to title will be center and bold, as it is on picture
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should make a custom layout for the `ActionBar`.

In Java:

```
getActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM); 
getActionBar().setCustomView(R.layout.actionbar);
```

In XML (this would be R.layout.actionbar):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical">

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:text="YOUR ACTIVITY TITLE"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:textColor="#ffffff"
    android:textSize="24sp" />
</LinearLayout>
```

You can then put more things in the actionbar XML if you wish.

Comment: Thank you for Reply , but here is no back button

Comment: Try with `getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);`

Comment: The result is same :(

Answer (score 3):

You need to set action bar with custom layout.
like this modify your code according to your need

```
action = getActionBar();

        LayoutParams lp = new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL
                        | Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);
        View v = ((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE))
                .inflate(R.layout.customlayout, null);

action.setCustomView(v, lp);

        action.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);
        action.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        action.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
```

**note**: you need to create your custom layout: R.layout.customlayout.